# Why is this java Stream operated upon twice?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The [Java 8 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) says:

> Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

So why the following code throws :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon
>   or closed

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1,2,3);
stream.filter( x-> x>1 );
stream.filter( x-> x>2 ).forEach(System.out::print);
```

The first filtering operation according to the API is not supposed to operate on the Stream.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This happens because you are ignoring the return value of `filter`.

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1,2,3);
stream.filter( x-> x>1 ); // <-- ignoring the return value here
stream.filter( x-> x>2 ).forEach(System.out::print);
```

[`Stream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) returns a *new* `Stream` consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate. But it's important to note that it's a new Stream. The old one has been operated upon when the filter was added to it. But the new one wasn't.

Quoting from [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) Javadoc:

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once.

In this case, `filter` is the intermediate operation that operated on the old Stream instance.

So this code will work fine:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1,2,3);
stream = stream.filter( x-> x>1 ); // <-- NOT ignoring the return value here
stream.filter( x-> x>2 ).forEach(System.out::print);
```

---

As noted by Brian Goetz, you would commonly chain those calls together:

```
Stream.of(1,2,3).filter( x-> x>1 )
                .filter( x-> x>2 )
                .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: So operate on a Stream is something different from traversing a Stream. I suppose that operate on a Stream change the internal state of it.

Comment: @ilias yes, it does change internal state of the Stream.

Answer (score 4):

`filter()` method uses the stream and returns one other `Stream` instance that you ignore in you example.

`filter` is a intermediate operation but you can't call filter twice on same stream instance

Your code should be write as follow:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1,2,3);
                               .filter( x-> x>1 )
                               .filter( x-> x>2);
stream.forEach(System.out::print);
```

As filter is an intermediate operation, "nothing" is done when calling theses methods. All the job is really processed when calling `forEach()` method

Comment: I think "nothing is done" is not correct. Something "has been done" when you call first filter, and that's why when you call second filter one the same Stream, it does not.

Comment: @MrinalK.Samanta it is the reason why i put under quotes ;) I means it is just declarative and no filtering is really done at this moment, but only when a terminal operation like forEach is called

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on Streams says:

*"A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once."*

You can actually see this in the source code. When you call filter it returns a new stateless operation, passing the current pipeline instance in the constructor (`this`):

```
@Override
public final Stream<P_OUT> filter(Predicate<? super P_OUT> predicate) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    return new StatelessOp<P_OUT, P_OUT>(this, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
                                       StreamOpFlag.NOT_SIZED) {
        ....
}
```

The constructor call ends up calling the `AbstractPipeline` constructor, which is set-up like this:

```
AbstractPipeline(AbstractPipeline<?, E_IN, ?> previousStage, int opFlags) {
    if (previousStage.linkedOrConsumed)
        throw new IllegalStateException(MSG_STREAM_LINKED);
    previousStage.linkedOrConsumed = true;
    ...
}
```

The first time you call filter on the source (line 2), it sets the boolean value to true. As you don't reuse the return value given by filter, the second call to filter (line 3) will detect that the original stream source (line 1) has already been linked (due to the first filter call) and hence the exception you get.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misuse of the `stream` which is detect when you attach more than one `.fliter()` to it.

It doesn't say it has been traversed more than once, only that it has "already been operated upon"

Comment: I cant tell the downvote here, I see this as *at least* a weird error message

Comment: @Eugene the operation on the stream occurs when filter() method is called, not when it is terminated.