# Java 8 Streams: Stream closed by intermediate operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm aware of the difference between [intermediate and terminal stream operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). However when I came across the code example below, I could not quite figure out the reason, why the filter operation in line 2 closes the stream leading the following exception in line 3:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon
>   or closed

Why does the intermediate filter operation close the stream?
Is this always the case when calling intermediate operations on a stream without terminal operation and/or without assigning it to a variable?

---

Code example:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
stream.filter(d -> d > 1);
stream.filter(d -> d > 2).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: The question is kind of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34677708/10406215
I did not find that one despite my search, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that method filter returns new stream. The old one is terminated after filtering.

```
/**
 * Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match
 * the given predicate.
 *
 * <p>This is an <a href="package-summary.html#StreamOps">intermediate
 * operation</a>.
 *
 * @param predicate a <a href="package-summary.html#NonInterference">non-interfering</a>,
 *                  <a href="package-summary.html#Statelessness">stateless</a>
 *                  predicate to apply to each element to determine if it
 *                  should be included
 * @return the new stream
 */
Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate);
```